# in PowerShell how to read database data into a variable

Tags: sql-server, powershell, variables

In a PowerShell script I need to get a value from a SQL Server table. The value needs to be stored in a PowerShell variable.  It's just one value -- not a whole dataset.

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not give it a try? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example using Sqlclient ( in a C# style:-) ).

```
$cn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT 1", $cn);
$cn.Open();
$yourVariable = $cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Write-Host "The value of yourVariable is $yourVariable";
$cn.Close();
```

Comment: The potential merits of your answer notwithstanding: something like `New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT 1", $cn);` is not C# style, it's pidgin PowerShell style that _accidentally_ works, but if you don't understand why, it will come back to bite you. By contrast, the `;` statement terminators are merely unnecessary, but otherwise benign.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's how I'm applying that technique to get the path for the Output file for a SQL Agent job step, so I can write to that file.

```
$cn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.output_file_name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps.job_id WHERE name = 'TestPS1' AND step_name = 'MyJobStep'", $cn);
$cn.Open();
$OutputFile = $cmd.ExecuteScalar();
$cn.Close();
Add-Content $OutputFile "Starting DEPLOY_SANITIZE_SCHEMA.sql __test_b"
Add-Content $OutputFile "##########"
```